# How to check if item has already existed in array in MongoBD?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How do I check if item has already existed in array? I have a schema model like below and I want to check if user id existed in any fields (cute, sweet, sexy...).

```
  const UserSchema = new Schema({
      ...
      vote_user: {
        cute: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], 
        sweet: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], 
        sexy: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
      },
      ...

  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using `$or`:

```
db.collection.find(
  {$or: [
    {cute: userId)},
    {sweet: userId)},
    {sexy: userId)}
  ]}
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HEFlFXSu2nj)

Comment: It work like a charm. Sincerely thanks! ❤️

Comment: but i have a question, we don't need to use $in to check the existence of item in array?

Comment: No. You would use `$in` if you had an array of `userId`s in your hand. For [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2VYZYTONw_0)